# jQuery, Javascript, Object Notation - Explanation of Differences in Callback Behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

Consider the following jQuery implementation defined using an object literal...

```
$(function() {

    var myObject = {

        methodOne: function()
        {

            $('#element').animate(
                {'marginLeft': '50px'},
                'slow',
                function() {
                    myObject.methodTwo();
                }
            );

        },

        methodTwo: function()
        {

            $('#element').animate(
                {'marginLeft': '-50px'},
                'slow',
                function() {
                    myObject.methodOne();
                }
            );

        }

    } // End myObject

    myObject.methodOne(); // Execute

});
```

For the record, the above code works just as expected. What I don't understand is why a subtle and seemingly harmless change like the following...

```
    methodOne: function()
    {

        $('#element').animate(
            {'marginLeft': '50px'},
            'slow',
            myObject.methodTwo() // No more anonymous function
        );

    },
```

... to both `methodOne` and `methodTwo` causes a browser error stating `too much recursion`. What's the difference between how I've declared my callback? Also, if I bring back the anonymous function declaration, but modify the object reference to look like this...

```
    methodOne: function()
    {

        $('#element').animate(
            {'marginLeft': '50px'},
            'slow',
            function() {
                this.methodTwo(); // assuming 'this' refers to 'myObject'
            }
        );

    },
```

... I get one good pass through `methodOne` and upon callback my browser freaks out because it cannot find `methodTwo`. My guess is that I fell out of scope somewhere, but I can't rightly decide where. Your insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break this down

```
        $('#element').animate(
            {'marginLeft': '50px'},
            'slow',
            function() {
                myObject.methodTwo();
            }
        );
```

In this example you pass a function object as a callback.  That function object is called when animation is done.  It has the `myObject` object shared via closure, so it can easily find it and call a method on it.  Awesome!

```
    $('#element').animate(
        {'marginLeft': '50px'},
        'slow',
        myObject.methodTwo() // No more anonymous function
    );
```

Here something different is going on.  As the callback here you are actually passing the return value of `myObject.methodTwo()`, and not the actual function object.  So since `methodTwo()` doesn't return anything, then `undefined` is actually passed as your callback.  Meaning that the `animate()` function thinks there is no callback.

So maybe you meant to try this!

```
    $('#element').animate(
        {'marginLeft': '50px'},
        'slow',
        myObject.methodTwo // No more anonymous function or invocation
    );
```

Well this still wouldn't work.  Now you are passing a function object for the callback, yes, but it will lose context (`this`).  It turns out that when you invoke a function object on it's own, then `this` is the global object.  Check this out:

```
var obj = {
  foo: function() { console.log(this) }
};

obj.foo() // logs obj

var func = obj.foo;
func() // logs window (the global object in a browser)
```

So you cant pass a function object directly in for a callback that is supposed to be invoked like a method with an object as the receiver.  Internally to the `animate()` method there, it executes `callback()` for you, which is a call that does not preserve the value of `this` for you at all.

So why didnt this one work?

```
    $('#element').animate(
        {'marginLeft': '50px'},
        'slow',
        function() {
            this.methodTwo(); // assuming 'this' refers to 'myObject'
        }
    );
```

When an anonymous function is invoke as the callback, just like breaking off a method, `this`  defaults to the window object.  So this code actually calls `window.methodTwo()`, which doesn't exist, and it explodes.

So the accepted standard JS way to do this your first way.

```
someFunc(arg1, arg2, function() {
  someObj.someMethod()
});
```

That should always work, even though it seems wasted because you invoking 2 function to do one thing.  But as you are discovering it's the least error prone.

Learning how `this` works in JS is a painful experience, but when you get it, you find that the rules are pretty straight forward and easy to manipulate.

---

If you still dont like that, you can do some tricky js magic.  Like [underscore.js bind() method](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind).

```
someFunc(arg1, arg2, _.bind(someObj.someMethod, someObj));
```

This returns a function that will always run with `someObj` as `this` which can safely be used as a callback.

Or if you want to try out CoffeeScript it has a fat arrow to preserve context, wich compiles to JS similar to what the underscore.js `bind()` method does.

```
someObj =
  foo: ->
    someFunc arg1, arg2, =>
      this.bar()

  bar: ->
    alert 'got the callback!'

someObj.foo()
```

In this case, the `=>` style of function declaration preserves the context of the scope where it appears, so this can be safely used.

Comment: +1 and solved for your very thorough lesson on scope and object handling. The devil really is in the details when it comes to Javascript, however I still consider it a really eloquent language (comparatively speaking, that is).

Answer (score 1):

when you give jquery the function to execute you are actually passing in a function pointer and not what you want to execute.. it basically does exec on the function reference that you passed and thus when you changed it to obj.method() it longer understood it..

The problem with the myObject.methodTwo() is that myObject.methodTwo() is evaluated before being passed as a function. Javascript and by extension jQuery expects a function pointer in cases like these. I.E. setTimeout function.

In the below usage, an anonymous function is created (just a block of statements) and is registered as the callback function. Note the use of 'function(){'. The anonymous function does exactly one thing: calls myObject.methodOne()

```
function() {
  myObject.methodOne();
}
```

regarding you second question in the callback function the this refers to  a different object and not your original object anymore and that is why that failed. if you want to pass your this reference to the callback function read this: http://thomasdavis.github.com/tutorial/anonymous-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

When you put the callback as `myObject.methodTwo()`, you are actually *invoking* `methodTwo` then and there.  Then inside `methodTwo` it does the same thing by calling `methodOne`...which calls `methodTwo`, which calls `methodOne`, and so on.  So you have an infinite recursion.

When you wrap that same line of code inside an anonymous function, it does *not* invoke the function immediately.  You are now passing the function itself, not the returned value.  The function using the callback then determines when (if ever) to actually invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

As zzzz and Paul stated, you're calling the function and passing its return value, rather than passing a callback. But you don't need to wrap that in an anonymous function to make it work - simply remove the `()` after the method and it'll work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This.methodTwo here is looking for local reference, This belong to current scope, so method two is define out side the current scope you can use . I just quick view the code and find the following suggestion.

```
 methodOne: function()
  {
 var that = this;
    $('#element').animate(
        {'marginLeft': '50px'},
        'slow',
        function() {
            that.methodTwo(); // assuming 'this' refers to 'myObject'
        }
    );

}
```